# awesomevalidation: message declared in strings.xml does not show up for spinner validation

Tags: java, android, validation

This is my string file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name"></string>

    <string name="location_prompt">Choose a location</string>

    <string name="invalid_email">Please enter a valid email</string>

    <string name="invalid_password">Please enter a valid password</string>

    <string name="invalid_first_name">Please enter a valid first name</string>

    <string name="invalid_last_name">Please enter a valid  last name</string>

    <string name="invalid_confirm_email">Email does not match</string>

    <string name="invalid_confirm_password">Password does not match</string>

    <string name="err_tech_stacks">Must choose one tech stack</string>

    <string name="invalid_location">Please select your location</string>

    <string name="invalid_gender">Please select your gender</string>


    <string name="gender_prompt">Choose a gender</string>

    <string-array name="gender_array">
        <item name="@string/gender">Gender*</item>
        <item>Third Gender</item>
        <item>Female</item>
        <item>Male</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

This is the part of java class file to validate the spinners:

```
     awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.gender, new CustomValidation() {
         @Override
         public boolean compare(ValidationHolder validationHolder) {
             if (((Spinner) validationHolder.getView()).getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Gender*")) {
                 return false;
             } else {
                 return true;
             }
         }
     }, new CustomValidationCallback() {
         @Override
         public void execute(ValidationHolder validationHolder) {
             TextView textViewError = (TextView) ((Spinner) validationHolder.getView()).getSelectedView();
             textViewError.setError(validationHolder.getErrMsg());
             textViewError.setTextColor(Color.RED);
         }
     }, new CustomErrorReset() {
         @Override
         public void reset(ValidationHolder validationHolder) {
             TextView textViewError = (TextView) ((Spinner) validationHolder.getView()).getSelectedView();
             textViewError.setError(null);
             textViewError.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         }
     }, R.string.invalid_gender);
```

The "invalid_gender" string is defined in strings.xml file. But it doesn't fire up when a correct option is not chosen from the spinner. Only in the dropdown box (spinner) "Gender*" portion gets highlighted in red. I want to fire the invalid_gender message defined in strings.xml ("Please select your gender") to be highlighted.

Comment: You need to validate spinner with selected position because in spinner first position is always selected.

Comment: @FalduJaldeep The first option is actually "Gender*". So it is always selected. When the first option is selected it should have fired up the error message defined in strings.xml, but it does not.

Comment: You can try loggin the value that you get from "getSelectedItem().toString()", to see if its actually selected